# Raspberry pi 3 with centos 7 error

Tags: pi-3

i have problems with my raspberry pi 3.

I use windows 10 on my laptot and it is ethernet connected.
I have installed centos 7 into a micro sd through Universal-USB-Installer (centos is without any graphic interface).
I put the micro sd inside the raspberry pi and connected it with ethernet to the router.
I found the ip address of the raspberry pi in the router configuration page (it is automatically set to static).

Tried a ssh connection with putty but i have the connection time out error.
Now i'm trying to ping it from my laptot prompt and the error is "host unreachable"

Can you help me?

Comment: Any reason you didn't use Raspbian?

Comment: @CoderMike just because i already used centos

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge (its a few years out of date for RH/Centos), SSH is not even installed by default on 6 (7+ you should be able to skip this step):

You need to use yum to install it first:

```
sudo yum –y install openssh-server
```

Then start it (not sure if enable auto-starts or not):

```
sudo systemctl enable sshd
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

**This does mean that the first boot has to be with a keyboard and screen.**

TBH - as per CoderMike I would use Raspbian as lots more support is available on the net for this.